# Unity playground patrol path of my fish not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm back so uh I don't know if this is gonna be clear to read.
Anyway my fish go pretty dang fast on a patrol path but then they just start vibrating in the wall or outside the wall whatever my lightspeed fish feel like, anyway speed isn't the issue cause it first was 123 speed then it was 100 that worked (temporarily) then i tried 55 speed that seemed to work a lot like i thought hay this is working, then unity went nah fish wont work no more.
It might be the patrol path but i doubt that so if possible can someone explain how to fix this please. This is stupidly confusing.
Its not the length of the patrol i know that for sure (the length they go is pretty much them going to another planet.

I hope this is easy to read i'm sorry if it isn't, I hate doing grammar.

Edit: [image: picture of where the fish are not moving]  the fish with the curly looking red whisker things are not vibrating in place only the ones with the straight whiskers and no whiskers.

Comment: Fyi we get your fish are unhappy. But thats like saying they are a funny colour.  We have nothing to go on

Comment: first is unity playground scripts, the patrol path is what is used on the fish (lets just call them objects) the objects follow the path pretty fast but at random points when they pass the middle area of my boss arena im making the objects just vibrate in place.